# WSAConnect - the remote server responds on both port 80 and 443

Tags: c, winsock, winsock2

I use WSAConnect to connect to a server whose site has the prefix http: \ That is, it seems like the remote server should connect only on port 80. But, in fact, I see that for some pages of this http site - WSAConnect completes successfully on port 443.

Is it okay? Is this allowed?

Comment: @Bence Kaulics, sorry. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WSAConnect` is for low-level socket communication, for example low-level TCP/IP sockets.

Web servers use HTTP for communication with clients, such as browsers. HTTP is an application protocol on top of TCP/IP.

By default web servers use port 80 for plain HTTP communication. Webservers can also support HTTP over a secure connection (HTTPS). The default port for this is 443.

So it is perfectly fine for a web server to be reachable on port 80 and 443.

In general, a single server can be reachable on any number of ports. Different ports are used for different protocols.

Comment: but why would one server serving one site need to use both http and https at the same time?

Comment: In the past most web servers only used HTTP over port 80. Only websites that needed the added security (banks, web shops) used HTTPS over port 443. Nowadays most web servers just use HTTPS for everything. When you connect to these servers over HTTP, the web server redirects your browser to the HTTPS address. Basically, the HTTP port is only for backwards compatibility.